# Converting regular expression to finite state machine

Tags: python, regex, state-machine, fsm

Would you have a hint at algorithm to convert any regular expression to a Finite State Machine (FSM). For instance, an algorithm parsing a regexp and adding states to the FSM appropriately? Any reference or deeper idea?

I am writting this with Python

Comment: isn't is what `re.compile` is basically doing ? Do you want to rewrite a regex engineyourself ?

Comment: Try compiling a regex with the `re.DEBUG` option.

Comment: is this homework for a class?

Comment: it is for fun only. I have written a generic fsm (very simple one), I would like now to have a function regExpToFSM() that will build a fsm corresponding to given regexp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Michael Sipser's [Introduction to the Theory of Computation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/053494728X). Chapter 1 gives detailed algorithms for converting a regular expression to a deterministic or non-deterministic finite-state automaton (DFA or NFA), in the context of proving their equivalence (a DFA, an NFA and a regular expression can match exactly the same classes of strings).

The general idea is: You convert a regular expression to an NFA, which can be done quite straightforwardly (`*` is a loop, `|` and character ranges are branch points). You then convert the NFA into a (much larger) DFA, which involves creating one DFA state for each *set* of alternative NFA states. The DFA has at most as many states as the powerset of the set of NFA states (e.g., an NFA with 3 states can get transformed to a DFA with at most 2^3 = 8 states), and can recognize any target string without backtracking. Read the book for the details.